# Minecraft, PermissionsEx and how group inheritance works

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm trying to setup permissions on a Bukkit server using PermissionsEx.

I've worked out how to add/remove permissions and basic group management, but I'd like to setup group inheritance.

The Groups I have are: default, member, moderator, admin and owner

I'd like it so that each group inherits from the one below.
What I've done so far is "pex group  parent set "

using that command ive done the following:
default has a parent of member, member -> moderator, moderator -> admin, admin -> owner

I'm not sure thats right though :/ when i look at the permissions for default, it shows lots of permissions some saying "from member", "from moderator", "from admin" and so on.

Have I done it in the wrong direction?
I've looked at the documentation but it just shows the command and not a lot else.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems that you have done it in exactly the opposite order. (It would help if you also posted your script, though.)

When you 'inherit', it means the 'child' will *inherit* all of the parent's members and can also add its own. So basically what you did was, you let anybody (even `default`) use everything it inherited from every group all the way up to `owner`.
So basically what you need to do is:

1. define the `default` group
2. define `member` and set its parent (i.e. let it inherit from) `default`
3. let `moderator` inherit from `member`
4. and so on.

That should be it.

**Edit:** Yesterday at night I was pretty tired, about to go to sleep and a bit worried whether what I wrote would make any sense in the morning. Luckily it doesn't look that bad; so I'll even add an example now. :)

Make your yml file like this:

```
groups:
  Guest:
    default: true
    permissions:
    - modifyworld.*

  Member:
    default: false
    inheritance:
    - Guest
    permissions:
    ...etc
```

(I've named the default group `Guest` for clarity.)

Comment: You pretty much hit the nail on the head , but something to add: When make a group inherit from another do it in this format:  **First line (In line with perms, prefixes. Etc. for that group):**  inheritance:   **Second line (Directly below):** - <group being inherited from>

Comment: I'm using MySQL instead of a config file, so couldn't provide one. I was using the console commands to enter it one by one. I think it's the word parent (in the command) that thew me, the word inheritance and the method you detailed makes more sense to me, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

/pex group  parents set 
Thats the ingame command much easier then going through config!!