# How do I setup permissions.yml for a Spigot Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find the docs that explain exactly how to set this file up.  Even a simple example should be enough for me to figure it out.

Comment: Unsure if this is what you are looking for, but it may provide some insight: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63980/minecraft-permissionsex-and-how-group-inheritance-works/63989#63989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from the Bukkit wiki https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Permissions.yml but you should manage permissions with a plugin (such as LuckPerms).

Comment: "but you should manage permissions with a plugin" 
Why?

Comment: @stackers because Spigot doesn't have a way of giving player's permissions in-game. With LuckPerms, you can assign permissions to players using commands, create permissions groups, sync permissions across your network, etc.